# c# - How to execute a .Jar file with Arguments.Length > 8191

Tags: java, c#

I should starting a `.jar` several times like this

```
        string JavaDir = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\javaw.exe";
        string MinecraftVersion = @"1.12.2";
        string ForgeVersion = @"14.23.2.2611";
        string Version = MinecraftVersion + @"-forge-" + ForgeVersion;
        string ClientDir = @CurrentDirectory + @"\Client";
        string Assets = ClientDir + @"\assets";
        string Libraries = ClientDir + @"\libraries";
        string Jar = ClientDir + @"\versions\" + MinecraftVersion + @"\" + MinecraftVersion + @".jar";
        string Natives = ClientDir + @"\versions\" + MinecraftVersion + @"\" + MinecraftVersion + "-natives";
        string Arguments = @"-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Djava.library.path=""" + Natives + @""" -cp """ + Libraries + @"\net\minecraftforge\forge\" + MinecraftVersion + @"-" + ForgeVersion + @"\" + Version + @".jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\ow2\asm\asm-all\5.2\asm-all-5.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\jline\jline\2.13\jline-2.13.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\typesafe\akka\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.3\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\typesafe\config\1.2.1\config-1.2.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-actors-migration_2.11\1.1.0\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-compiler\2.11.1\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\plugins\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.11.1\scala-library-2.11.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-reflect\2.11.1\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-swing_2.11\1.0.1\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\scala-lang\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\lzma\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\vecmath-1.5.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\minecraftforge\MercuriusUpdater\1.12.2\MercuriusUpdater-1.12.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.9.Final\netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.25\authlib-1.5.25.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\mojang\realms\1.10.19\realms-1.10.19.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\7.1.0\fastutil-7.1.0.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.4-nightly-20150209\lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar"";""" + Libraries + @"\com\mojang\text2speech\1.10.3\text2speech-1.10.3.jar"";""" + Jar + @" net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --username " + Username + @" --version " + Version + @" --gameDir """ + ClientDir + @""" --assetsDir """ + Assets + @""" --assetIndex 1.12 --uuid " + UUID + @" --accessToken " + AccessToken + @" --userType legacy --tweakClass net.minecraftforge.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker --versionType Forge";
        Client.StartInfo.FileName = @"""" + JavaDir + @"""";
        Client.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
        Client.Start();
```

but the argument's limit is 8191 char and my argument is greater than the limit.

How I can run it?

EDIT: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Use a file rather than an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your program receive a file as an argument and read it.
The file would have one or more lines depending the number of arguments you'd like to pass to the program.

Your program would need to receive the file and parse it line by line.